# How to find a file recursively in folders using PHP?

Tags: php

How to find a file in folders with sub name of the file means the file need to be searched is not fully named but it is a part of the name for example I want to search the file namely 'hello_world_123.png'. I did not enter full name of the file but one or some words only, for example the 'world_' is my input but the code should search the full name of file.

In short the searching may work like operating system's search in file explorer or file manager.

My code as below but I am stuck with matching the name of file in if condition.

```
$file_name_ = 'recursive-1.php';
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $folder_path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);  

foreach($it as $file) {     

    $file_info = pathinfo($file);       

    $patt = '/^(\w+)\.+('.$file_name_.')\.+(\w+)*$/';
    $result = preg_match($patt,strtolower( $file_info['basename'] ),$match );       
    if ( $result ) {    
        echo 'File found';
    } else {
         echo 'File not found';
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem 2: `recusive-1.php` isn't a substring of `find-recursive-1-file.php`. You should explain better what are the rules to "match" a filename.

Comment: It's changed to `recursive-1.php`@CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: \w doesn't contain dash-character. And if you want just to check the presence, try strpos function

Comment: You're not correctly matching the extension of the file (`.php`) see these other questions for help about getting the extension of the files you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054997/find-all-php-files-in-folder-recursively

Comment: I have used the concept from this question and searched lotes on Google @Tonin

Comment: Thanks! `strpos()` function where helped me find the file@JessieJackson

Comment: I have added my answer myself

Comment: But what if position found at `0`? @JessieJackson

Comment: It's mentioned in docs. You should use strict comparision (===) with false. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

To find the file in directory recursively, with or without extension, the following code is helpful.
The file name is not complete name (the part of the file name) so the `strpos()` function will find the position of file name which is partial.

```
$file_name_ = 'recursive-1.php';

//Splitting the file to get the file name without extension
$file_name_ = explode('.',$file_name_);
$file_name_ = $file_name_[0];

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $folder_path,   RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);  

//looping for all files in given directory
foreach($it as $file) {     

    $file_info = pathinfo($file);       
    //$patt = '/^(\w+)\.+('.$file_name_.')\.+(\w+)*$/';
    //$result = preg_match($patt,strtolower( $file_info['basename'] ),$match );       
    //$result = strpos(strtolower($file_info['filename']),strtolower( $file_name_));    
    $result = stripos($file_info['filename'], $file_name_); 
    if ( $result === flase ) {    
        echo 'File not found';
    } else {
        echo 'File found';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use a [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-match.php) for that. You can look if the file in the folder has part or the full name of the file you are searching for.

Comment: Who and why down vote my answer, that's the solution of the problem, you use preg_match to find text that contains what you want? What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: preg_match is already used in the question and doesn't solve the problem alone.

Comment: @Tonin when I answered the question he wasn't using preg_match(), yes it wasn't a complete answer but it was a starting point and I could've expanded on that, personally I don't think jumping and throwing a minus to a comment is a correct way to go, but hey, who am I to judge, btw, have you checked the edits of the question before down voting?

Comment: If you make your answer evolve along the question, then I'll have the opportunity to review my vote. As is, your answer is not useful to anyone looking at the question.