# How to get the full path of a file only from it's name, using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get the full path of a file by searching it with it's name.

E.G

```
Some_Function( "main_background.jpg" );
```

Should return

```
"public/assets/images/main_babckground.jpg";
```

"main_background.jpg" is the name of the file which i want it's full path.

How can i achieve this in PHP ? TIA

EDIT:

1) My php script was not in the same directory as the file i wanted to find.

2) The question was already asked before, and the given best answer has worked for me too.

Here is the link [Find all .php files in folder recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054997/find-all-php-files-in-folder-recursively)

Comment: where is the directory of your php file?

Comment: If you want to do a recursive search, through directories, for the given file, you might want to look at `glob()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

if your file is in same directory so you can use `realpath()` function it will return absolute path learn more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php:

```
<?php
    echo realpath("main_background.jpg");
```

Comment: That'll only work if the PHP file is in the same directory as the image file

Answer (score 0):

`__DIR__` constant will give you absolute path to the directory of the current PHP-file.

Since your file seems to be in the same directory just add `__DIR__` infront of the filename.

---

If you want to search a file, take a look at [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/de/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php) and combine it with `strstr` or `preg_match`

Comment: `__FILE__` will give you the path to the PHP file including the filename, `__DIR__` would be better.

Comment: Oh right, thanks @CD001

Comment: But the file OP want to get the full path of IS NOT in the same folder as the script

Comment: Since he only knows the filename he has to search for the file (second part of my answer)

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is a note about the RecursiveDirectoryIterator ... if that was expanded upon to show usage this would be a pretty good answer; but since the question itself is practically a duplicate it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @CD001 Right, if that was expandde into at least an example it would be an answer and not just a comment

Comment: @CD001 But the Dup has a couple of examples including the use of RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Comment: @RiggsFolly - that's why I said it probably wasn't worth it ;)

Comment: Additionally on the linked page are some examples :)

Comment: @modsfabio - yes but a link isn't really an answer, if the site you're linking to was nuked from orbit there would no longer be an answer - general rule of thumb, if you're putting an answer you need to fully answer on-site - even if you're quoting an external resource.

Comment: Alright :) But now it's not worth anymore to edit the answer ..